# Mobilefirst Push Notification doesn't work if app removed from recent list

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working with MFPF CLI version 7.1.0.00.20160129-1927, I'm using my own project (Ionic) and the hybrid sample provided by the getting started module. In both case I'm able to subscribe and receive push notifications. But when I remove the app from recent list I'm not more able to receive push notification. The adapter message returned is with a positive result. The phone is an Android 5.1
Are there some issue we have to care about to have it working when the app is removed from recent list (but user is subscribed)?
Thanks on advance for help.

Comment: Are you sure your GCM registration token persists the removal?

Comment: If you remove the app from the "recent list", it just means you have quit the app. This does not mean that push will not work. Push notifications arrive *to the device*, tapping a notification then *opens the app*. In other words, are you saying that push works only if the app is open? notifications do not arrive to the device at all if the app is quit? (that, of course, does not make sense). Please be clearer about the problem.

Comment: Hi Idan, push notifications arrive until I have closed the app but available on the recent list. If I remove it, I'm not able to have the push notification on my device

Comment: Hi Shark, from the MFPF server console the user is registered even if I remove the app from my phone recent list. The adapter answer with success and found the user registration.

Comment: If you catpure logs from your device ( logcat) , you should see if the notification is reaching the device or not . Capture logs while you do - a) application is running and you receive notification b) application is cleared from recent list and then server sends out a notification

Comment: @Marco what is the status of this question?

Answer (score 0):

Below are four possible scenarios and their expected and tested results:

1. App is open and in the foreground
2. App is open and in the background
3. App is closed by sliding it off
4. App is force-closed

Notifications are received and the app can be opened in scenarios 1-3, as expected.
Notifications will **not be received** in the device in scenario 4, as expected.