# MobileFirst and Ionic Push notification callback

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have an Ionic project and I added a push notification callback handler as explained in official documentation (my expectation is to have some alert when inside the app and a notification arrive), but it is never invoked.

```
  WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
            "myPush",
            "PushAdapter",
            "PushEventSource",
            pushNotificationReceived);
```

Here the question is where I have to place the pushNotificationReceived function to be called ? I try in index.js and inside the controller as a function, but I do not have success.
Thank for help

Comment: The callback should be defined within the js where you register the callback .Are you receiving push notifications in your device ? Is it that , the notification is not being displayed within the callback?

Comment: Is this really different than your existing question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549330/mobilefirst-push-notification-doesnt-work-if-app-removed-from-recent-list

Comment: Yes, the other question is about the recent list cleaning, this one is when the app is opened and in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the sample application for push notifications?.
The sample demonstrates implementation of push notifications APIs. https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/event-source-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/

See the supplied main.js file: https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/EventSourceNotifications/blob/release71/apps/HybridEventSource/common/js/main.js

Comment: Hi Idan, the answer is yes, and the sample is working as expected, but I'm not able to replicate it with Ionic framework. The callback function is not called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include callback function in ionic inside the app.js file after "Successfully connected with mobile first server".

```
     WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then(
            function (response) {
              //alert("successfully obtained a token from the server");
                MFPPush.initialize (
                   function(successResponse) {
                       //alert("Successfully intialized");
                        MFPPush.registerNotificationsCallback(notificationReceived);
                   },
                   function(failureResponse) {
                        console.log("Failed to initialize");
                   }
                );
                MFPPush.isPushSupported (
                    function(successResponse) {
                       //alert("Push Supported: " + successResponse);
                    },
                    function(failureResponse) {
                        console.log("Failed to get push support status");
                    }
                );
                MFPPush.registerDevice(
                    function(successResponse) {
                        //alert("Successfully registered");
                    },
                    function(failureResponse) {
                        console.log("Failed to register");
                    }
                );
                function notificationReceived(message) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(message.alert));
                }
         }, 
         function(response) {
            //alert("res"+JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log("Unable to obtain a token from the server: " +            JSON.stringify(response));
            if(JSON.stringify(response.status) ==  403){
                 console.log("The Application is disabled on this Device");
                 ionic.Platform.exitApp();
            }
        }
     );
```